# How to use React-i18next with Table antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have following Table component created with `antd`:

```
import { Table } from "antd";

const dataSource = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "Mike",
    age: 32,
    address: "Downing Street"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "John",
    age: 42,
    address: "Downing Street"
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  }
];

const CustomTable = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomTable;
```

Now I would like to add translations to each `columns` name. I would like this solution to be obtained with the help of `React-i18next`

A simple example of using this library is the following code:

```
const {t} = useTranslation();

t('textToTranslate');
```

Additionally, I have some translate.json where are my translations key & value like:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "age": "age"
}
```

How I can add translation to each `columns` -> `name`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way of generating columns and use translation as a typical react prop:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "Mike",
    age: 32,
    address: "Downing Street"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "John",
    age: 42,
    address: "Downing Street"
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    title: "tableHeadings.name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "tableHeadings.age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "tableHeadings.address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  }
];

const CustomTable = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <Table dataSource={dataSource}>
        {columns.map((column) => (
          <Table.Column
            key={column.key}
            title={t(column.title)}
            dataIndex={column.dataIndex}
          />
        ))}
      </Table>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is passing the columns as props to your CustomTable component and then adding the translation to the title as follows:

```
const CustomTable = ({ columns }) => {
const { t } = useTranslation();

const tColumns = columns.map((column) => ({
    ...column,
    title: t(`${column.title}`),
  }));

return (
  <>
    <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={tColumns} />
  </>
 );
};

export default CustomTable;
```